# How to change the color of the mesh of 3D model using Three Js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have tried the below code but it is merging the color with default color or texture not changing the color.

```
root.getObjectByName(model).material.color.setRGB("255","0","0")
root.getObjectByName(model).material.color.setHex(0x00ff00)

root.getObjectByName(model).material.color.setRGB("255","0","0")
root.getObjectByName(model).material.color.setHex(0x00ff00)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set a material color via `setRGB()` or `setHex()`, you definitely overwrite the previous value. However, the material color is *always* multiplied with the sampled color from the material's `map` property. The only way to prevent this from happening is to assign `null` to `material.map`.